# Can't share internet from iPhone to MacBook using USB

Tags: macos, iphone, network, usb

Using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (it's latest for MackBook Pro 2012) and iOS 14.7.1 with a Lightning to USB Cable.

Reset Network settings, clicked "Trust", Personal Hotspot is on, still doesn't work.

Network panel shows Attached status of iPhone USB.

So, how to make to share Internet from iPhone to MacBook using USB?
[image]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the entire window?

Comment: @Andra Yes, I mean Personal Hotspot on iPhone. And it's turned on.

Comment: @KevinGrabher now it's the entire window:)

Comment: Does it work over WiFi? Do you have another Mac to test if it works there via USB?

Comment: And can you check if "Internet Sharing" is turned off in "System Preferences" -> "Sharing"

Comment: @KevinGrabher it works over WiFi, and Bluetooth Tethering too. I'll check with mac mini, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @KevinGrabher "Internet Sharing" is turned off, right

Comment: If the iPhone is the issue you could try resetting network settings on it (keep in mind that this will remove all the WiFi configs and password!). I fit's the Mac another post on AskDifferent suggests the issue could be with the .kext https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43431/iphone-usb-tethering-problem

Comment: Could you try to simplify the problem analysis? [•••• return ••••] 1. On iPhone, turn off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth to be sure the Hotspot is turning on on the USB interface since it will be the only network interface outside of the mobile phone one). [•••• return ••••] 2. On Mac, create a new "network configuration" (which Apple call a location but it isn't), name it "iPhone USB" and only activate this interface within this configuration so as to be sure MacOS won't think another interface is on.